# How to solve '/dev/fd/63: ... command not found' bash script error

Tags: bash, scripts

When running these commands in the Ubuntu 18.04 CLI manually (as root) everything works fine.

```
sudo apt install snapd -y
snap install lxd
```

But when I put those same lines in a bash script I get these errors:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 71: sudo apt install snapd -y: command not found
/dev/fd/63: line 72: snap install lxd: command not found
```

I separated the commands in another super simple script and there snapd gets installed but for the second command I still get:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 8: snap install lxd: command not found
```

Here's the super simple bash script that was written with GitLab's online IDE:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt autoremove -y

apt install snapd -y
snap install lxd
```

I start the script with

```
bash <(curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: PRIVATE' 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1234567/repository/files/lxd-install-test.sh/raw?ref=master')
```

Comment: Please show your script and how you start it. The `/dev/fd/63` at the beginning of the error messages looks highly suspicious. Also the fact that the error message lists the entire line as the command that was not found, instead of just the actual command. (`sudo` or `snap`, respectively.) Is it possible that you put non-breaking spaces instead of regular blank characters in your script? How did you write the script in the first place? Which editor did you use?

Comment: The original script contains some stuff I'd rather not like to share, that is why I made the simpler test script.
I guess my ISP uses a minimal install of Ubuntu where it is not included.

Comment: Checking the output of the HTTPS call in the chrome inspector did show some &nbsp;s. I have no idea how they got there. But thank you for that tip! Would you like to put that up as the answer @Tilman?
Also I will change the title to better reflect the mistake I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your script file for nonstandard blank characters such as the non-breaking space. (`U+00A0` or HTML `&nbsp;`)

The error message `command not found` normally reports the name of the command that was not found. (eg. `sudo` or `snap`.)
But in your case it reports the entire line as the command.
This is a hint that the blank characters separating the arguments from the command name and and from each other are not regular blank characters (`U+0020`), but some other characters that appear blank on the screen.
The most frequently encountered such character is the non-breaking space (`U+00A0`).
This may happen if code is transferred via copy&paste from a web page or other source of formatted text.
The `bash` command line parser does not consider such a character as a delimiter and therefore doesn't recognize the command verb.

Comment: Thank you for that good explanation!